# Recover output from Python script stuck in a .filename.py.swp file?

Tags: python

I ran a Python script that looped through 160,000 lines, hit an API, and (was supposed) to dump all of the output to a `.txt` file.

I ran out of disk space, and discovered a `.filename.py.swp` that is 21GB large. I vim'd it, and I see a bunch of data that the API responded with.

Sadly, there's a bunch of binary characters in there.

How can I clean up this Python `.swp` file to extract my JSON from it?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using vim ?

Comment: Yes, but the .swp file was not generated from VIM. I am under the impression that the .swp file was created by "saving the state" when the machine ran out of space.

Comment: I don't know, I think vim created this as a recovery file for your python script and it's not related to your program's output, but I may be wrong of course. Is there really nothing in this 160 kloc that looks like JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'strings' command in Linux, I was able to extract SOME data. This command removes binary data and returns the parameter you give it (the filename) in straight string format.